# File or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrprovider missing in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dll, .net-assembly

I moved my Entity Data Model from one project to onother project. By cutting the data model folder and pasting in different project. Everything went fine, but when I try to update the 'Model from Database' I get the error of missing assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrprovider after providing it the SQL connection. I tried addding some references but it did not helped. I am presently unable fix this problem. Below is the screenshot of error.

[image]

Comment: un-references all the dlls. then again do the references. Change the Target Framework. Save it Close it. Open it again. Build -> Clean Solution. and Rebuild it. Hope this works for you.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Tried it Mohit. But still same problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem got fixed by installing the following MSIs.

**SQLSysClrTypes.msi**
and 
**SharedManagementObjects.msi**

These can be found here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295

Choose the MSI according to machine architecture x64 or x86. Do not forget to restart Visual Studio. Try rebooting machine if that not works.